# Anime with kids deemed dangerous to humans because of their abilities, protected by a centuries-old man who can transform into a monster

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime about six years ago (2012).

From what I remember there were three sides of the story. The human race, a special organization that "protects", and a group of kids with abilities that were deemed dangerous to humans and hunted down. Sounds almost like a comic, but way better.

The protector of the special kids could transform into a monster with a split face (two different colors) and couldn't die. He was actually centuries old, and carried the hatred of what had happened to his village.

One of the kids was a girl with an incredible and magical voice. When she sang the organization could track her.

It was complicated and had a great storyline!

Comment: where did you watched it?

Comment: and how are the characters?

Comment: I had a cable package that I could watch a lot of anime on but I can't remember the channel name, or the name of the tv company sorry to say. I thought the characters were well done and I believe they were drawn but I could be wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds a lot like *[Towa No Quon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towa_no_Quon)* (2011), a 6-part OVA series which has a transforming ancient protagonist and a girl with a magic voice.

Main character transforms into a monster to save his friends, who have special powers, from a secret organization that is hunting them. His village was destroyed and he's got a healing factor + immortality.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot!